# How to style Tikz arrow tip for state-loop?

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows, automata

I want to have a state-node with a loop, where the arrow tip is customized (here with `-triangle 60`). How do change the arrow tip a loop uses?

Heres a short example. I expect the loop to have the same arrow tip as the edge from start to end.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,abstracton,11pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (loop-node) at (0,0) {node};
\node (path-start) at (2,0) {start};
\node (path-end) at (2,2) {goal};
\path
(path-start) edge [-triangle 60] node {path} (path-end)
(loop-node) edge [loop above, -triangle 60] node {edge} ();
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Now I would like to understand why its not working as I expect, and how I can change the arrow tip for loops.

I also tried to change the style of the loop with 
`loop/.append style{-triangle 60}`, 
with and without `\tikzset`, but that seemed to be a dead end.

Comment: Oh, and Welcome to TeX.SX!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have no idea why your example doesn't work, but specifying the arrow tip with `->, >=triangle 60` instead works for me.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,abstracton,11pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (loop-node) at (0,0) {node};
\node (path-start) at (2,0) {start};
\node (path-end) at (2,2) {goal};
\path (path-start) edge [-triangle 60] node {path} (path-end)
(loop-node) edge [loop above,->, >=triangle 60] node {edge} ();
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The "correct" way would be to use `every loop/.append style={-triangle 60}`, as `loop above` is a shorthand for `[above,out=105,in=75,loop]`, with `loop` introducing a `to path` that uses the `every loop` style. Your way is much more pragmatic, though, and works just as well in this case (some things, like `shorten <` do not).